# linux: grant write access to a folder for a single user

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

let's say we have dir1 with mode 755 root root and I want user1 to be able to write to the directory, but I don't want to add him to the root group or change the user or group ownership of the directory.  Is there something along the lines of `chmod user1+w` for only granting additional access to a single user without disturbing ownership or adding the user to another group?  ACLs perhaps?

CentOS 6.4 EXT4

Comment: When I used a Mac, chmod allowed you to add an ACL to a file using `chmod +a 'john deny write' file1` or something like that.  Does the FreeBSD chmod allow ACLs and the GNU version not allow it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have acl support installed (package `acl`) and mounted the FS with acl support (option `acl` in `/etc/fstab`), you can try the following:

```
setfacl -m "u:user1:rwx" /path/to/dir1/
```

This should add `user1` to the list of users allowed to write to that directory.

More infos with `man setfacl` and `man getfacl`.

Comment: Should we run `sudo chmod 700 /path/to/dir/` before hand to remove if there is previously defined user permissions?

Answer (score -1):

Yes the answer is ACL. We currently config ACL on a thousand of user web server

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate your answer with an example? Just a thought.